# Adding and Updating labels on screen

Tags: label, cesiumjs

The problem that I have seems pretty easy and obvious, but I couldn't find a way to do it with Cesium. I want to have labels, or info box to show the progress of the problem, so labels are adding to the screen in time (I can have all labels at the beginning of the program and change the color of them by time too).

1. I don't know how to create label such that its location only depends on the screen or page (for example top of the page) and not on the position of an object, such as world or cesium widget. 
   (a kind of position with direct visual representation)
2. To update labels, can I define two intervals with different texts?
3. Can I make my labels as buttons which are appearing sequentially and then for example will change the current time of the program?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want labels fixed in screen-space, the best way is to simply overlay HTML on top of the Cesium widget.  You can have a translucent background, and clickable HTML buttons.  You can use `viewer.clock.onTick` to update the labels based on the current time.  Here's an example, click "Run code snippet" at the bottom of this.

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationHelpButton: false
});
viewer.scene.globe.enableLighting = true;
viewer.clock.clockRange = Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP;

var hourPlusButton = document.getElementById('hourPlus');
var hourMinusButton = document.getElementById('hourMinus');
var timeLabel = document.getElementById('timeLabel');

// The clock tick listener gets called every animation frame.
// Keep it fast and try not to allocate any memory if possible.
viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function(clock) {
    var elapsed = Cesium.JulianDate.secondsDifference(
        clock.currentTime, clock.startTime);
    var hours = Math.floor(elapsed / 3600);
    elapsed -= (hours * 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);
    elapsed -= (minutes * 60);
    timeLabel.textContent = hours + ' hr ' + minutes + ' min ' +
        elapsed.toFixed(1) + ' sec';
});

// Button click callbacks are free to allocate memory.
hourPlusButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    viewer.clock.currentTime = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(
        viewer.clock.currentTime, 3600, new Cesium.JulianDate());
}, false);

hourMinusButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    viewer.clock.currentTime = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(
        viewer.clock.currentTime, -3600, new Cesium.JulianDate());
}, false);
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden; font-family: sans-serif;
}
.controlPanel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.8);
  color: #edffff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
<div class="controlPanel">
    <h5>Elapsed time: <span id="timeLabel"></span></h5>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="cesium-button" id="hourMinus">-1 hour</button>
        <button type="button" class="cesium-button" id="hourPlus">+1 hour</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh Thank you, But I want to add buttons in time and then let them handle the time, for example after one hour, I will add a button which said one hour has already been passed, and then whenever I press that button, the time will restart at that one hour. I will check if I can follow your instruction for that purpose.

Comment: I also tried to use window.setTimeout for creating my buttons, but it doesn't work, they haven't been delayed for the amount of time I declared, I guess its because my cesium time is different than current time.

Comment: Yes, Cesium time can be different from realtime, and can move at different speeds in both directions.  I've updated my answer to include elapsed time, so you can see how many hours etc have gone by.

Comment: You know what I want to do, I want to show that I reach home, by time 12:00 then I want to show that I went to school by time 8:00, and add all of this label\button as soon as I reached the destination. that's why I start using   `window.setTimeout` , but I will see if I can sync its time with cesium, by using `clock.currentTime`. Other than that I think it's very tricky to use `onTick `method for this case.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can stop event that I schedule by `onTick` method, because when I press the button for resetting the events, it seems previously scheduled events are happening again.

Comment: This sounds like a separate question, but generally `onTick` is not for scheduling events, as it fires 30 ~ 60 times per second.  But, you can get Cesium's current time from this event, compare it to a time of interest, and determine if a given button/label should be visible or not at this time.

Comment: I asked it as separate question. Thanks!